# Free modules over a PID

Tags: abstract-algebra, exact-sequence, principal-ideal-domains, free-modules

Could anyone please tell me Is my prove for this question ok?
Let $R$ be a PID and $M$ a fg module. Prove there exist free R-modules like $F_0$ and $ F_1$ with the fg base and $0\to F_1\to F_0\to M\to0$ is a short exact sequence.

My prove is: $M$ is homomorphic to a free module $F_0$ so we have $0\to \ker(g)\to F_0\to M\to0$
$R$ is noetherian so $\ker(g)$ is fg.
Since $R$ is PID any submodule of F is free so is $\ker(g)$.
So we can write $F_1=\ker(g)$
Am I correct ?

Comment: Your typing and spelling so far can be improved:)

Comment: Sure, but isn't the point to construct $F_0$? (this is not difficult, of course)

Comment: @user43687 since M is homomorphic to a free module I called it $F_0$ So I thought I need to show how to construct $F_1$

Comment: @user43687 Right, but why is $M$ homomorphic to a free module? You should construct it. Take the module freely generated by the generators of $M$ and the the canonical map $\phi:F_0\to M$ sending each generator to itself...that's your homomorphism. After that, yes, the kernel of this map is a submodule of a free module, hence free.